# Wiring a property into bean via setter after initializing bean itself

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

### Some context

The situation is I am creating a beanA that need some dependencies to be injected, but beans that needs to be injected are created after the beanA, so

### The question

I was wondering is there any way for me to firstly create a beanA and inject some field values after they are created. And yes i am not talking about @DependsOn, I particulary want to know if it is possible to achieve such behaviour using setter injection, is there a way to delay injection not using @DependsOn annotation?